# Why is my sssd.conf file missing after installing sssd?

Tags: 12.04, ldap

I'm new to linux and decided to play around with building a server to learn more. I have been following the following guide: http://www.danbishop.org/2012/06/02/ubuntu-12-04-ultimate-server-guide/
Everything has been going well. I have a functioning Kerberos Realm, and DNS and DHCP are working great. But, I installed SSSD and I have no /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file. I noticed when SSSD was installing it showed

```
Setting up sssd (1.8.2-0ubuntu1) …
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript sssd, action “start” failed.
… because /etc/sssd/sssd.conf is not available yet
Setting up libpam-sss (1.8.2-0ubuntu1) …
```

Any thoughts as to why I don't have an `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf file`? I did find a `/etc/init/sssd.conf` file. But, that doesn't appear to be what I need. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Server.  I must be missing something.
Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an example sssd.conf at `/usr/share/doc/sssd/examples/sssd-example.conf`. You can copy it with:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/sssd/examples/sssd-example.conf /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

[UPDATE] In Ubuntu Server 14.04, the default file is located at
`/usr/share/doc/sssd-common/examples/sssd-example.conf`
resulting in a new command of:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/sssd-common/examples/sssd-example.conf /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
```

In general, you'll want to look for an `sssd` subdirectory in `/usr/share/doc` that has an example .conf file somewhere in it, and copy that file to `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`.

Comment: Thank you.  That sort of helps.  I can copy it over.  But, shouldn't it have been created when sssd was installed?  What might have prevented that from happening?

Comment: The file isn't in the deb-package and the only thing dpkg does at installations is unpacking deb-packages ;) Try it yourself: Open a *.deb at /var/cache/apt/archives/ with for example file-roller.

Comment: Well, it makes sense that it would be missing then.  Now to figure out what I missed.  Thanks.

Comment: @Robert Please mark my answer as the right, if you think it is ;)

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATE]** In Ubuntu Server 14.04, the default file is located at
`/usr/share/doc/sssd-common/examples/sssd-example.conf`
resulting in a new command of
`sudo cp /usr/share/doc/sssd-common/examples/sssd-example.conf /etc/sssd/sssd.conf`